# Angular2 RC5 Cannot find 'default' in 'module.js' (lazy load)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple angular 2 app so I can try get lazy loading right.

Before bundling the app works correctly.

I am bundling the to the following folders :

- /js/app.bunlde.js - Default app.module with all the dependency's
- /app/login.module.js

When I navigate to /#/login I get : Cannot find 'default' in './app/login.module.js'

Checking the network tab login.module.js is loaded.

**routes.app.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Home } from "./home.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: Home },
  { path: "login", loadChildren: './app/login.module.js'}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true });
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'
import { Login } from "./login.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Login],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        { path: '', component: Login }
    ])
]
})

export default class LoginModule { }
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try RC6. Please note there is a small change in the way you specify loadChildren path. Good luck.

```
{ path: 'heroes', loadChildren: 'app/hero/hero.module#HeroModule' }
```